# Nodejs express cors error, headers are set in both client and server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I have built a NodeJS/ExpressJS app, and deployed it to Heroku, I also have a very basic html page deployed on another domain, as this is how I will use it in the real world. But I keep getting the same cors errors no matter what I try.

Here is my node app

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config()

app.use(express.json());
app.unsubscribe(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'html')

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

app.all('/export/pdf', (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        // PDF Generator Logic....
        res.send(buffer)
    })()
})

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, err => {
    console.log(err || `Server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

This is the client side which sends the request..

```js
function handlePDF(body) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'mydomain.com/export/pdf';
    body = JSON.stringify(body);
    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.responseType = 'blob';
    req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.onload = function (e) {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            if (req.status === 200) {
                console.log(req);
            } else {
                console.error(req.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(req.statusText);
    }
    req.send(body);
}
```

As you can see I have both the request header set on the client side, and also within express, BEFORE my routes, as explained in similar questions.

I have tried using the npm package cors too and passing it into my route as described in its documentation, but that also didnt work.
I have tried removing the header from the client side request, thinking it would be handled entirely server side since I have full control of that, that also doesn't work.

I feel like I have tried everything, can anyone with a bit more node/express experience see where I am going wrong?

Comment: "Nodejs express cors error" — **What** CORS error? You need to quote the exact error message, not describe it in vague terms.

Comment: "headers are set in both client and server" — **Don't** set headers which are only allowed on a response on your request. At best it will have no effect, at worst it will convert a simple request to a preflighted one and make everything harder.

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'appdomain.com/export/pdf' from origin 'mydomain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Is the exact error, sorry I missed that from my question.

Comment: I removed the line " req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); " from the request, but still get the same error.

Comment: The same advice applies to every single question like this (of which there are often multiple a day).  Open the Chrome debugger.  Go to the network tab.  Then make your Ajax call.  Then, look at the exact request the browser is sending and the exact response you get back from the server.  Usually, the answer will be obvious from that.  In half the cases, the browser decides to pre-flight with an OPTIONS request which you need to have your server handle.  In the other half, your request ends up being different than you expected or the server CORS code isn't working so you need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the code you posted to work by using

`var url = "http://example.com/export/pdf"`

instead of

`var url = "example.com/export/pdf`

Also, setting the CORS headers on the client is not necessary. CORS is a security feature implemented by the browser. It only depends on the headers sent by the server, not those sent by the client. Setting them on the client is pointless. For more info, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) explains it excellently.